# How to include object in Ruby attributes method (ActiveModel::Serialization)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby, active-model-serializers

I have an object I would like to serialize to JSON and I'm trying to use the ActiveModel::Serialization::JSON module to achieve this. My attributes method looks something like this:

```
class MyClass
include ActiveModel::Serializers::JSON

def attributes
{
  'attr1' => nil,
  'attr2' => nil,
  'object1' => nil,
  'object2' => nil
}
end
```

This works fine until I try to run `JSON.parse(myclass_instance.as_json.to_s)`; I get this error related to the internal objects in MyClass:

```
JSON::ParserError: 757: unexpected token at '{"object1"=>#<MyClass::object1_field1>...}'
```

How can I specify my internal objects in the attributes method so that this does not happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `as_json` function is special, it returns what should be *in* the JSON structure, but it does not actually return JSON.

What you want is this:

```
JSON.parse(instance.to_json)
```

Have a look at what `as_json` emits.